# launchMode stops extra from transfer in intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have been trying to figure out why my Intent would not transfer string data from one activity to another activity? I seems I had set launchMode = singleTask in the manifest folder and when I changed launchMode to standard the Intent code worked as expected.
The MainActivity is the first activity in the stack I am guessing that I made the setting a number of months ago to try and prevent the user from using the back button to navigate back to the password log in page. (MainActivity)

I kind of get the Back Stack idea but WHY would this setting inhibit the intent from transferring data. my test for transfer was a System.out.println statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have activities A and B. A is the one with `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. A starts B. B then starts A, causing the existing instance of A to return to the foreground.

In that case, A is called with `onNewIntent()`, and *that* `Intent` will have the extras from B.

`onCreate()` is only called when an activity is created.

Comment: so my construct for the intent was like Intent i = new Intent (bla.this,A class) if I understand i should have used onNewIntent thanks for quick reply

Comment: @Grendel: Yes. The first `Intent` for an activity goes to `onCreate()`, since the activity is being created. If, via `Intent` flags or `launchMode` or whatever, you wind up reusing an existing activity instance, the second and subsequent `Intents` go to `onNewIntent()`, since the activity is already created.

Comment: I believe you but I can not enter onNewIIntent(A.this,B.class) in the sending activity you are saying use onNewIntent in the receiving activity ? as is code create intent first                                                              Intent i = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("key","true");
                startActivity(i);                                                                   
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            dothat = extras.getString("key");

Comment: @Grendel: Like `onCreate()`, `onNewIntent()` is a callback method. You do not call it yourself. You override it, in activity A as depicted in my answer.

Comment: so using singleTask does it have any advantage ? and if so would you care to elaborate off to read my Commons Ware book more to this question it need a whole lot more learning thanks

Comment: @Grendel: `singleTask` is not recommended for most cases, IIRC. Personally, I have never had the need for it, outside of a book example or two.